# Downsampling Image

Tags: image-processing

Can you suggest me a good downsampling algorithm for an image. I explored area averaging method, but I am looking for better. I am using good in the sense that it should be less computational expensive and output image should be good by look and free from aliasing, checkboard effect etc.

Comment: What downsampling algorithms have you explored so far? What are your criteria for the output image looking nice?

Comment: @auspicious99 thanks I added in question.

Comment: It is not possible to have an artifact-free method without reducing the space of images, nor providing details about the level of downsampling you when to use

Answer (score 1):

To avoid checkerboard effect, you could consider a Gaussian smoothing filter.

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice discussion with image examples for the open source application Imagemagick: [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/) and [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/filter/).